# Some page display 50% width

Tags: css, responsive-design

When I resize the browser in a small size like 360px, the display of some pages are 50% width that usual width. How to fix this?

Here's the [link](http://www.homecredit.ph/promos/free-ktv-party/)

Thanks!

Comment: It is because of the padding and margin.

Comment: check your media queries, check paddings, check margins, this `@media (max-width: 480px)` is where you have to look into css and adjust the css according to size like 360px, all div elements

Comment: @ManojKumar width is not defined in `@media (max-width: 480px)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this in your css :

```
       .ak-container, body.boxed-layout {
       padding: 0;
       width: 100%;
       }

      .no-sidebar #primary {
       float: none;
       margin: 0 auto;
       width: 100%;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution add css property min-width for class: promobody

```
.promobody {
  margin-left: 60px;
  min-width: 225px;
}
```

min-width keep a minimum width for your class so contents will show within that width in small devices.

OR

you can set margin and padding for elements in page according to device width using Media Query.
Check these : [Media Query](http://learnlayout.com/media-queries.html) & [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.promobody {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

}
```

Comment: .promobody is only use in promo page. Promos pages are not the only display 50% width